# how to define different docroot based in parameter in URL

Tags: url-rewriting, virtualhost

A webiste contains PHP-scripts that are accessed by specifying the environment as parameter in the URL, to connect to the proper database: `https://website/scriptbase/subdir/script?environment=(name of environment)`. All except website are hard-coded in a program, the website is defined in database and can be changed by the program administrator. 
To allow temporary changes in the web application, to be accessed by just a few environments, I'm looking for a way to set this up in such a way that only these can access the changed code, where all others are still accessing the unchanged code. This is referred to via an IP-based virtual server on all ports (80, 443).
My idea is to copy the current subdir to subdir2, apply the changes in that directory tree, and  no other adaptations. All references within the code are relative so that should be covered as well.
To access this, I want to create a second virtual server, same IP address but on a different port. Environments that should access that path would only need to change the server specification to use that port, allowing them to switch easily without assistance. Or I could create a rewrite rule, based on the content of parameter "environment" to use that virtual server, by direct access of by redirect using that port number, but that would require user assistance if they want to switch.
(why switch? well, current code works, changed code contains enhancements but even after testing, it can still contain blocking errors so reversal should be as easy as possible).
Of course, I could instead define another server, but that would require a DNS registration and certificate, resources I would like to prevent used.

Can this be done, and if so, I would like some examples, or is there a better way to get this done?

BTW. Environment is:
`# uname -a`
`Linux <server> 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 21:19:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
`# httpd -v`
`Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`
`Server built:   Dec 15 2015 15:50:14`
`#`

Answer (score 0):

Has been tackled - the way I wanted defining the same server on a different port> However, this caused a problem: web-access (via browser) went Ok but access using http-protocol from within a program fails. So I changed to subdomain (easy chnange).

This caused another issue, because of HSTS but there are other issues....